# Accessing Properties of one Object from another Object

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to object oriented programming.
I have two classes in class-modules:

ClassA

```
Public Time As Double
```

ClassB

```
Public Sub Progress()
    ClassAObject.Time = 5
End Sub
```

This is the code running in the subroutine

```
Public Sub Progressing()
    Dim ClassAObject As New ClassA
    Dim ClassBObject As New ClassB
    Call ClassBObject.Progress
End Sub
```

The subroutine `ClassBObject.Progress` seem to not be able to access `ObjectA`. I think how I refer to the object might be wrong. How do I fix this?

Comment: You should be careful not to create a circular reference (objA references objB and in return objB references objA) as it leads to memory leaks. See this article for further info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716190(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class B does not know of class A. There are many ways to do this, but one way is to make the `.Progress()` sub take an input.

Code in ClassA:

```
Public Time As Double
```

Code in ClassB:

```
Public Sub Progress(ClassAObject As ClassA)
    'Assuming that you have a .Time property in ClassAObject
    ClassAObject.Time = 5
End Sub
```

Code in Main:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim ClassAObject As New ClassA
    Dim ClassBObject As New ClassB
    ClassBObject.Progress ClassAObject
End Sub
```

Comment: This won't compile.

Comment: This won't compile either... swap `classA` and `ClassAObject`

Comment: I changed everything, to match your naming. Hopefully this will work...

Answer (score 2):

You could pass an instance of `ClassA` to the `Progress` method. So for example:

Change `Progress` method to:

```
Public Sub Progress(a As ClassA)
    a.Time = 5
End Sub
```

And call it like this:

```
Public Sub Progressing()
    Dim ClassAObject As New ClassA
    Dim ClassBObject As New ClassB
    Call ClassBObject.Progress(ClassAObject) ' <--- pass instance of ClassA
End Sub
```

I would recommend giving your classes and objects more descriptive names, even if you're just practicing. It will make it easier for you and others to read and understand your code. For example, `Dim apple As New Fruit` is always easier to understand than `Dim ClassAObject As New ClassA`.